# What is going on inside the $.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, twitter-bootstrap

I am stumbling upon a problem that I have seen before, but that I couldn't solve before. I will likely stumble upon it again in the future, so please, someone explain it to me what is going on?

In the partial snippet of javascript below, I have a function that populates a screen, including an order combobox (twitter bootstrap). When I click on one of the order items in that combobox, it should invoke the function clsModCampaigns.blnCompaniesListReload().

For a reason that I don't understand, once inside the '$.each' iterator, the global object reference 'objModCampaigns' is lost? I get a successful alert '1', but not an alert '2'.

Within the $.each, I would like to use 'objModCampaigns.arrOrderBy' instead of 'this.arrOrderBy', but the $.each iterator only seems to work this way. Why is it working this way??

What is going on with 'this', or with variables/objects assigned in the root of the class with 'this'?

Is $.each just special??

```
function clsModCampaigns(objSetSystem, objSetModuleBase)
{
  objModCampaigns = this;
  arrOrderBy = {
    intID: 'ID',
    strName: 'Name'};

  [...]

  this.blnScreenCampaignInitialize = function (fncSuccess,fncError, intID) {
    $.each(this.arrOrderBy, function (strFieldName, strFieldDescription) {
      if(strFieldName != 'datDeleted' || objSystem.blnHasPerm("CAMPAIGNS_DELETED")) {
        strOrderByID = "ulCampaignsCompaniesListOrderBy" + strFieldName;
        $("#ulCampaignsCompaniesListOrderBy").append('<li><a href="#" id="'+strOrderByID+'">'+strFieldDescription+'</a></li>');
        $("#"+strOrderByID).unbind("click").bind("click", function() {

          alert("1");
          objModCampaigns.arrCurrentShownCompanies.strOrderBy = strFieldName;
          objModCampaigns.blnCompaniesListReload();
          alert("2");

        });
      }
    });
    return true;
  };
}
```

Comment: Inside `$.each()` http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js

Comment: why aren't you using `var` for your variable declarations?

Comment: @naomik: should I? It seems to work this way in other places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is

```
$.each(this.arrOrderBy, ...);
```

You want

```
$.each(arrOrderBy, ...);
```

The reason for it is the `this` context on that line is different because it is inside a new function `this.blnScreenCampaignInitialize`.

This is just a part of how JavaScript works

```
var message = "hello";

function welcome() {
  console.log(message);
}

welcome(); // "hello"
```

---

**P.S.** use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

If you don't use `var`, you'll be attaching all of your vars to the global object.

```
function hello() {
  foo = "bar";
  console.log(foo);
};

hello();          // "bar"
console.log(foo); // "bar"
// Holy smokes! `foo` has escaped our `hello` function!
```

Compare that to

```
function hello() {
  var foo = "bar";
  console.log(foo);
}

hello();          // "bar"
console.log(foo); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
// much better
```

Now let's see a terrible example

```
function a() {
  b = 5;
  return b;
}

function b() {
  return "function";
}

console.log(a()); // 5
console.log(b()); // TypeError: number is not a function
```

This is happening because we didn't use `var` properly. We first define `b` as a function but after running `a()`, `b` is now set to `5`. The second log statement is the equivalent of trying to run `5()` because `b` is no longer a function.

---

**P.P.S.** it's pretty unconventional to prefix your vars with `str`, `int`, `fnc`, `obj`, or `cls` in JavaScript.

I understand you're a "VB guy" according to your comments, but that's no excuse for bringing your own conventions to the language. I see in your profile that you're fluent in Dutch, English, German, and French. I would recommend you treat learning programming languages much the same as spoken languages: each of them have their own explicit set of rules and conventions.

Here's a heap of [free JavaScript books](http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/) for you. I hope they can help you learn some more basics.

---

**P.P.P.S.** Overall, your function is really big as it is, and I can see you already truncated some of the code with your `[...]`. The whole thing could probably benefit from some better composition.

If you paste all of your code, maybe someone could help you better.

Comment: I tested this, you are correct, it works your suggested way of removing 'this.'. But that doesn't explain it, merely make it even more confusing !! How can the scope change suddenly from a local function to a global class function, within $.each() ????

Comment: On a smaller note, do you have a reference about the importance of 'var'? Also, I agree that it is unconventional in jscript to prefix vars with type indicators, but I am a VB guy, sticking to old-grown type clarity principles...

Comment: I've made some edits to address your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
What is going on inside the $.each() ?
```

Regarding you question title, I'm trying to answer:

```
// each function in source
function (obj, callback, args) {
    //...
}
```

Check the source of complete [$.each function](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each) by yourself, you can see any function's source code just by typing the function name in the appropriate text box (the second on top).

Here in `each` function, the array/object passed in to the `each` function (the first argument) is being run through a loop and each value is being passed in to the `callback` (second argument) and that call back is getting executed like:

```
callback.apply(obj[i], args);
```

So, the passed `callback` in the each function is being executed each time the loop occurs ad the current value in the loop is passed as the argument of `callback` function along with the third argument `args`.

If your function `function clsModCampaigns(){ //... }` is a normal function then `this` inside this function points to global `window` object. so just use:

```
$.each(arrOrderBy, ...);
```

instead of

```
$.each(this.arrOrderBy, ...);
```

Because, `arrOrderBy` is within the direct scope so `arrOrderBy` is accessible directrly. For example:

```
function someThing()
{
    var x = 'y'; //<-- this scope (everything inside someThing) is
                 // global for somethingElse inner function

    function someThingElse)(x) //<-- possible to use directly
    {

    }
}
```

The keyword `this` behaves differently depending on the context. Check about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on `MDN`.